# Is there benefit in calling non-inlined function from inlined function?

Tags: c, inline

Example:

```c
static inline void function(arg1, arg2){
    non_inlined_func(arg1, arg2);
}
```

From what I understand this will still require a call to `non_inlined_function` so is there a point?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In that special example it doesn't make much sense. But if you add some code around calling the non-inlined function, it clearly can be useful.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "_inlined function_" with "_`inline` function_". These are different concepts. How would you know whether `function` or `non_inlined_func` are inlined? That is up to the compiler and will depend on the context.

Comment: Inlining makes no difference in behavior, except for speed and memory usage. How much the difference is depends on the code and the compiler.